# Are Holo-Packs predetermined?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-2016

There are holo-packs spread throughout the levels that give you up to three holo-cards. Are they three random cards every time or is each holo-pack always going to give you the same three cards? You can trade 5 duplicates for any card you want but it would be nice to know just to wait for a certain card if it is a guaranteed drop later on.

Comment: I noticed that when collecting a pack, I would sometimes be prompted to press `Options`, but other times I wouldn't. This seemed to coincide with when I obtained a new card. During my first playthrough, I picked up a number of packs with no prompt (therefore they were all duplicates), which makes me think that they are random. I believe the only exception is the RYNO holo-packs, which are pre-determined or at least not able to give duplicates (so you actually complete the set).

Comment: Indeed. And, with regards to the RYNO ones, each one is only found in one place.